# Using"light" style from Mapbox

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-studio

Mapbox showcases a beautiful "light" style: https://www.mapbox.com/maps/light

However, this style is not available in the style gallery: https://www.mapbox.com/gallery/

Would anyone know where/how to get the "light" style json in order to import it in Mapbox Studio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it!

Templates are available when creating a new map from scratch.

"Light" is a variation of the "monochrome" style.